# vim cd'ing to git root

Tags: git, vim

I'm trying to cd into my project's git root from vim so that my Ctrl-P works properly. I often work in project's where I *don't* want Ctrl-P to look up to the git root so I have it set up to only look for the nearest folder with a `.gitignore`.

On the command line I can do something like `cd $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)` but when I try the same thing in vim with `:!cd $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)` it hides vim and just shows a blank output. I was told the ! in the vim command line would allow me to run bash commands. Am I missing something.

Comment: `:!cd` is not the same as `:cd`.  Also, Vim has no idea of `$(...)`, use `system()` instead.  Better yet, use something like `:exec 'cd' fnameescape(fnamemodify(findfile('.gitignore', escape(expand('%:p:h'), ' ') . ';'), ':h'))` instead of running `git`.

Comment: Thank you. I changed `findfile` to `finddir('.git')` since in this case I *don't* want to find the .gitignore file but the git root of the whole project. I will accept if you make this an actual answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
:exec 'cd' fnameescape(fnamemodify(finddir('.git',
    \ escape(expand('%:p:h'), ' ') . ';'), ':h'))
```

The `escape(..., ' ')` is necessary for the enclosing `finddir()`.  `fnameescape()` makes sure `cd` doesn't gripe about special characters.

Answer (score 9):

You can use backticks to run shell commands and pipe the output into Vim commands like `:cd`:

```
:cd %:h | cd `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`
```

This sets the current directory to the directory of the current file and then runs `:cd` with the git directory from the `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` command.

Alternatively, if you use [fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) you can use the `:Gcd` command.

For more help see:

```
:h :cd
:h backtick-expansion
:h :bar
```

Comment: No `fnameescape()`.  Naughty, naughty. ;)

Comment: The `:Gcd` is also exactly what I wanted. I am using fugitive so it works in my case. I up-voted but selected Sato's answer because it works for those who don't have fugitive.

Comment: @adam-beck Beware that `:Gcd` only works if you start run Vim against a file maintained by `git`.  If you start Vim with no file you're out of luck.  This is a known problem with `fugitive`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura, `:cd %:h | exe 'cd ' . fnameescape(substitute(system('git rev-parse --show-toplevel'), '\n', '', ''))` would be the proper way to do it. Better yet use `systemlist()` function, `:cd %:h | exe 'cd ' . fnameescape(get(systemlist('git rev-parse --show-toplevel'), 0))`, but `systemlist()` function is rather new.

Comment: @SatoKatsura, You are correct `:Gcd` works against the current file, `%`.  It does however also work if you [start Vim in a git controlled directory](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/45) as a special case.

Comment: You can also replace `substitute(system(...), ...)` by the shorter `split(system(...), "\n")[0]`, but that can also fail if `system()` fails.  Then again, if `system()` fails you lose anyway.

Comment: Re: `fugitive`: sure, but if you start in the project's directory you don't need to `:Gcd`.  `fugitive` is surprisingly kludgy on the inside...

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't work with `echo`? For example: `:echo \`pwd\``

Comment: `:echo` is looking for a valid expression. Using backticks to run a shell command only really work on vim command which look for files e.g. `:find`. See `:h backtick-expansion` & `:h expression`. You are likely looking for `:pwd` or `getcwd()`. e.g. `:echo getcwd()`